# Looking a way to automatically change one element on a website to another one. Hyperlink to a button exactly

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

So i have hyperlink at a webpage that is:

```
<a href="123.com" onclik="this.href+='&amp;sub=442028';" name="1909e63d" class="cs"><b>456</b></a>
And i want it to be a button instead of hyperlink.
```

Like:

```
<input type="button" class="butt1" name="but" value="456" onclick="123.com'">
```

I tried to change it inside chrome dev tools and it works, well obviously since i jsut give it href adress manually. Sadly i have no expirience with tampermonkey or greasemonkey at all and very limited javascript knowledge. Wonder if it possible and would appretiate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code based on your example...

First, you need to get the link

If it is only one link, find it based on a selector:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a.cs');
```

Create the input

```js
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'button';
input.className = 'butt1';
input.name = 'but';
input.value = '456';
input.onclick = 'window.location.href=' + a.href;
```

Note: A better way is to use `input.addEventListener('click', function)` instead of `onclick`.

Replace the link with the button

```js
a.parentNode.replaceChild(input, a);
```

If there are more than one links, then you need to get them and loop through them e.g.

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll('a.cs');
```

Comment: Oh, tnx alot! Solution doesnt work as it is, but now i atleast have idea what to do, just gonna research little bit more.